# Automatically change PBI's state to Done when all the associated tasks are Done in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs

Spent a while trying to figure this one out as our old Scrum for Team systems template did this in previous version of TFS, however I can't find a way to make a PBI automatically change its state to Done when all the associated tasks are done in TFS 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the Conchango Scrum Template in TFS2010? Part of this template was a webservice which was updating the PBIs. I'm not sure if there is a new version for TFS2012, which still has this functionality. If not, it might be necessary for you to write this on your own.

Comment: Yes we were using the Conchango Scrum Template, and it was that webservice functionliaty that I was looking for in the TFS2012. Still haven't found anything so might look at writing our own. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an out-of-the-box solution, but [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) is a plugin that is designed to handle this scenario.